# Validate method parameter name between interface declaration and implementation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

**Issue**:

```
public interface ITest
{
    String JoinString(String first, String second);
}

public class Test implements ITest
{

    @Override
    public String JoinString(String first, String second)
    {
        return first + second;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static int Main(Object[] args)
    {
        var inst = (ITest) new Test();
        inst.JoinString("a", "b");
    }
}
```

This correctly returns string "ab". But if you change the interface and swap the parameters

```
public interface ITest
{
    String JoinString(String second, String first);
}
```

then the method still returns "ab" instead of expected "ba". This expectation is based on the parameter name "first" and "second".

**Question**: How do you validate that parameter names from interfaces match the names in implementation? Preferably during build time with a build error.

Comment: **SonarLint** might mark this renaming of overriden parameters. It does that for C#. And you might do more with SonarLint, making a list of company checked violations.

Comment: @Joop Sadly it doesn't report it. I couldn't find any similar rule in the settings either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer IntelliJ versions, this is under *Editor->Inspections->Java->Naming conventions->Parameter name differs from parameter in overriden or overloaded method* - no need for external plugins anymore for this:[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is probably as close to a solution as I can get. Unfortunately it doesn't abort compilation yet. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78625

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin in the Jetbrains' marketplace that implements this feature.
You can find it [in this link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15354-method-parameter-order-inspection).

If you want to see the implementation of that plugin, you can take a look at its [GitHub's repository](https://github.com/johnnyleitrim/IntelliJParameterOrderInspection).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have older unsupported version of intellij so I can't test, but I don't think this solves my problem. The issue for me is that the interface is auto generated from swagger and only the interface implementation is in our code. Nobody actually calls the interface directly. It is used by spring to create a rest api.

Comment: @Horato the plugin is no longer compatible nor supported, because this inspection is now provided in core IntelliJ inspection bunch (just disabled by default AFAIK)